# How to retrieve data passed in .ajax request in node.js?

Tags: ajax, node.js

I am trying to retrieve the data that I am passing from my homepage javascript index.ejs to a function in routes/index.js

**index.ejs**

```
$(".user-create-btn").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/users/create/",
        data: {username: "John123"},
        type: "post",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("test")
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(e);
    location.reload();
  });
```

**routes/index.js**

```
/*Create new user*/
router.post('/users/create', (req, res) => {
  //how can i retrieve the the data of the username here?
  models.User.create({
    username: username,
  })
});
```

Comment: I think you want https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require('express')
    , router = express.Router()
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/users/create', (req, res) => {
  var body = req.body,
    username = body.username;

  models.User.create({
    username: username,
    ...
  })
});

app.use(router);

var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Mention that he has to include the `body-parser` module

Comment: Nope, just say that he has to require the `body-parser` module in his server file.

Comment: `res. sendStatus(204)` to reply on the HTTP request.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI, code 201 would be more appropriate, since OP is creating something.

Comment: @ppovoski:thank u for info.. anyway, i mean to not forget `end`ing the response. .. so it can be  `409` if there is an error.. so on...